# Laravel - syntax error, unexpected ''phone'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ']'

Tags: laravel, postman

I am using Laravel-5.8 as backend for an application. I have written all the Api for the endpoints.

**Laravel: ApiController**

```
        $request->validate([
                    'first_name' => 'required',
                    'last_name' => 'required',
                    'email' => 'required|email',
                    //'email' => 'required|email|unique:users|max:255',
                    'phone' => 'required|max:14',
                    'business_name' => 'required',
                    'truck_type' => 'required',
                    'truck_required' => 'required',
                    'quote_origin' => 'required',
                    'quote_destination' => 'required',
                    'commodity' => 'required',  
                    // 'weight' => 'required',
                    'loading_date' => 'required' 
        ]);
        $clientquote = new ClientQuote([
            'first_name' => $request->first_name,
            'last_name'=> $request->last_name,
            'email' => $request->email
            'phone' => $request->phone,
            'business_name' => $request->business_name,
            'address' => $request->address,
            'comment' => $request->comment,
            'truck_type' => $request->truck_type,
            'truck_required' => $request->truck_required,
            'quote_origin' => $request->quote_origin,
            'quote_destination' => $request->quote_destination,
            'commodity' => $request->commodity,  
            'loading_date' => $request->loading_date
        ]);
        $clientquote->save();

            $mainData = array();
            $mainData['to'] = $clientquote->toArray()['email'];
            $mainData['from'] = "support@tsllimited.com";
            $mainData['subject'] = "Client Quote";
            $mainData['content'] = "Your Quote have been successfully received. You will hear from us shortly through the provided email. Thank you!";

            $this->mailSend($mainData);

        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Quote Successfully Sent!'
        ], 201);
}

public function indexClientQuote(Request $request) {
        return response()->json(ClientQuote::get());
}
```

When I tested the Request on the POSTMAN, I got the error shown below:

[image: postman error]

I don't know why it's expecting ']'.
What could have caused the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you missed **','** after **email**

```
'email' => $request->email
'phone' => $request->phone,
```

To

```
 $clientquote = new ClientQuote([
        'first_name' => $request->first_name,
        'last_name'=> $request->last_name,
        'email' => $request->email, //here you missed comma
        'phone' => $request->phone,
        'business_name' => $request->business_name,
        'address' => $request->address,
        'comment' => $request->comment,
        'truck_type' => $request->truck_type,
        'truck_required' => $request->truck_required,
        'quote_origin' => $request->quote_origin,
        'quote_destination' => $request->quote_destination,
        'commodity' => $request->commodity,  
        'loading_date' => $request->loading_date
    ]);
```